# Validate a string has the same on the front half as the back half

Tags: regex

I have a situation where i need to search for a value where the front have is equal to the last half with a marker character that seperates the two.

Example Data:

```
433315283V005984521
005984521V005984521
```

Ideally the Regex should match the 2nd data but not the first data.  The character `V` is the demarcator between the two sides

I tried doing Look Aheads and Look Behinds but was unsuccessful with my implementations

```
V{1}(?=\d{1,})
```

Maybe i was doing it wrong, not to mention i don't do alot of value checking with regex and use it more for validation of data.

Comment: did you want to match `V005984521`?

Comment: nope, `V` is the demarcator.  But @AmalMurali got the pattern i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to achieve this:

```
^(.*?)V\1$
```

The `(.*?)` captures what is before `V`, and stores it into the backreference `\1`. If the part before `V` and after `V` are the same, the match is successful.

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aM4wH9)

Comment: Didnt even think about the group reference.  Awesome, got exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings_to_compare = ( "433315283V005984521", 
                           "005984521V005984521" );

foreach my $compare ( @strings_to_compare ) {
    my ( $first_bit, $last_bit ) = split ( "V", $compare );
    if ( $first_bit eq $last_bit ) { print "Match: $compare\n" };
}
```